# Finding mean squared error of estimators of $\pi$ when $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,\pi)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, mean-square-error

Now I am really struggling to understand the definition of the mean squared error.

The question I am working on:

$X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,\pi)$. Find the mean squared error of the estimators $\widehat{\pi}=\frac{X}{n}$ and $\stackrel\sim \pi = \frac{X+1}{n+2}$.

Given that $E(X)=n\pi$ and $\operatorname{var}(X)=n\pi(1-\pi)$.

I am trying to get my head around the notation used in the definition of the MSE.

Now the bias is the expectation of $X$ minus $\pi$? Then the MSE would be the given variance plus the bias squared? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Bias of $\hat\pi$ is $E(\hat\pi-\pi)=E(\hat\pi)-\pi$ and yes, MSE of $\hat\pi$ is $\operatorname{Var}(\hat\pi) + (\text{bias}(\hat\pi))^2$. Is the 'squiggly line ontop' something like $\stackrel\sim \pi$?

Comment: Yeah that’s it, I’ve found another post that’s similar so I understand it now but thanks,, do you mind editing the post and putting it in?

Comment: You can add a link to that post.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988884/mean-squared-error-mse-of-parameter-p-in-binomial-distribution-intuition


This is a similar and answers my question.